# Cannot copy to server using PSCP

Tags: tomcat, pscp

I have downloaded PSCP from:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

and added it to the PATH in windows 7. I now try to copy a file to a tomcat using the following :

pscp -P 8081 bob.txt mm@http://repository:/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/bob.txt

based on the info from:

http://e-articles.info/e/a/title/Transfer-files-from-the-command-line-with-PSCP/

but I just get the error:

ssh_init: Host does not exist

If I login as the user 'mm' to the server using putty I can cd to the var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps/ directory just fine. Any ideas on why the host is not located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really sure your host is "http://repository" ? I would guess it is only "repository". Try that.